# I can't restore my Android Studio preview setting

Tags: settings, preview

My Android Studio preview is working fine.
But I made my preview screen to new window. When I wanted to make it inside the Android Studio again, I can't find a way! How can I restore my preview setting as Default? (to be located inside the Android Studio preview tab. Not separated window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these instructions

1.Select the Preview Window

2.Go to Window menu -> Active Tool Window
Docked Mode in Window menu

This will make preview window in docked mode there will be settings icon you can change it if you want to change it again